# maven filtering API in MOJO

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I try to develop a maven plugin  with resource filtering.
In my code i have this :

```
Resource file = new Resource();
file.setDirectory(buildDir.getAbsolutePath());
file.addInclude("appcfg.xml");
List<Resource>  listResources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
listResources.add(f);

MavenResourcesExecution mavenResourcesExecution =
         new MavenResourcesExecution ( listeResource, outputDir, project,
                                              encoding, buildFilters,
                                              Collections.<String>emptyList(), mavenSession );


mavenResourcesExecution.setUseDefaultFilterWrappers(true);
mavenResourcesExecution.setInjectProjectBuildFilters(true);

mavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources( mavenResourcesExecution );
```

When i launch my mojo,  appcfg.xml file is copied in the output directory but properties are not replaced by values.

my appcfg.xml  is like this :

```
< test name="${project.groupId}__${project.artifactId}__TU" / >
```

Could you help me to find where is my mistakes.

thanks

Comment: Why not using the usual resource plugin which supports such kind of filtering already? Special needs ?

Comment: Ah..You need to activate filtering in the resource like **file.setFiltering(true);**. Apart from that i would suggest to get the resources via a plugin configuration and not hard coded.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise,  file.setFiltering(true) solved my problem.  I need hard coded this because my plugin generate the file on the same phase of filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks khmarbaise, file.setFiltering(true) solved my problem. I need hard coded this because my plugin generate the file on the same phase of filtering